# Вызов функции view через redirect с параметрами

Tags: python, django, redirect

У меня есть **urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, {'check': False}),
]
```

Есть **view.py**:

```
def index(request, check=False):
    if check:
        return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the test index.")
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('autorisation:check_auth'))
```

В методе ***index*** используется параметр ***check*** - авторизирован пользователь или нет. Задумка такая: при первом входе на страницу параметр имеет значение ***False*** и исходя из этого перекидывает запрос на авторизацию. Авторизация должна вернуться в этот же метод ***index***, но с ***check = True***.

***Redirect*** из метода ***check_auth*** (не рабочий):

```
def check_auth(request):
    return redirect('app_test:index', check=True)
```

Как правильно реализовать данную затею? Желательно не изменяя views.py - без параметров url.

Ошибка:

```
NoReverseMatch at /auth/check_auth
Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'check': True}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Answer (score 0):

Функцию перенаправления вы написали правильно. Другое дело принимает ли url именованные аргументы. Если не принимает, но надо ставить именованные, или передавать уже как позиционные. Если ничего не принимает, то передавать что-то бесполезно.

Вообще у джанги есть встроенные декораторы аутентификации.

```
@login_required
def my_view(request):
   pass
```

Декоратор удобный, если пользователь не вошёл, то его перенаправит на страницу входа. А потом вернёт на ту страницу на которую он хотел изначально.

Answer (score -1):

А зачем такое извращение?

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    и дальше по тексту
```

UPD: не привык к здешним комментам, извиняюсь

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, {'check': False}, name='index'),
    url(r'^$', views.index, {'check': True}, name='index_authenticated'),
]

def check_auth(request):
    return redirect('app_test:index_authenticated',)
```

Comment: У меня своя логика авторизации. Можно конечно на каждой странице проверять сессию и активен ли её ключ. Но хотелось бы это оставить на стороне вьюхи отвечающей за авторизации и просто обращаясь к ней возвращая параметр: да / нет.

Comment: Ну раз своя логика...
а так, 
url(r'^$', views.index, {'check': False}, name='index'),

Comment: url(r'^$', views.index, {'check': True}, name='index_authenticated'),

Comment: и return redirect('app_test:index')
вместо 
return redirect('app_test:index', check=True)

Comment: Такой вариант изначально пришел в голову :) Можно и без параметра: просто каждый раз из index отправлять в autorisation:check_auth и уже из его логики отправлять на страницу авторизации или на другой view, соседний с index. Но как-то оно не красиво, хотелось бы обойтись одним методом.